# Zend Framework 2 send a 302 response on GET after redirect, when running codeception tests

Tags: php, zend-framework2, http-redirect, codeception

I'm using Codeception TestGuy to run functional tests on my ZF2 app, and all the stuff have worked great so far, but i'm having troubles with redirects at this moment... When the app redirects i got the following error message: `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`.

OK, it must be in loop. After some hours doing investigations, i've found a possible cause for this error. The `FollowingRedirect` of test suite is based on HTTP response codes, then during the redirecting to a page X, app sends  a 302 response, the next request should be a GET on page X, and expect a 200 response, right? But the GET on page X returns a 302 response too, on browser GET returns a 200 response though.

If i put `$this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(200);` on the X page action, it works fine on both browser and tests. Will I need to `setStatusCode` for every redirecting or this is a bug of ZF2?

Thanks in advance!
P.S. Sorry for english :D

Comment: Yes, it seems like there may be a bug affecting certain actions, as not all redirects are causing the issue. It's worth noting that this behavior isn't consistent across all actions. Have you noticed any patterns or commonalities among the actions where the issue occurs?